Angular 17: Relative paths in style file of a node_module of micro-frontend not working in shell application
I have helloApp micro-frontend application and there is a shell application (parent).
In micro-frontend, I am trying to show flags in a dropdown and its working if i run the micro-frontend as a standalone application. But, when micro-frontend is run from shell application, it does not. It is not able to find the flag svg images due to relative path issue. The svg relative paths are in "node_modules/flag-icons/css/flag-icons.min.css".
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flag-icons
Using NX in the project. Configuration in project.json looks like following:
"assets": [
    "apps/helloApp/src/assets",
  {
    "glob": "**/*",
    "input": "node_modules/flag-icons/flags/1x1",
    "output": "./assets"
  }
],
"styles": [
  "apps/helloApp/src/styles.scss",
  "node_modules/flag-icons/css/flag-icons.min.css"
],

